# iOS and Android c socket programming + GUI

Tags: android, ios, c, sockets

I'm going to develop an application for iPhone (iOS) and Android. It should run as a unix daemon gathering data and send it using a TCP/IP socket.

We already have a c socket util written in Windows. My thought is to OS cross compile for BSD and Linux and then use it on iOS and Android.

Ive looked a bit at "Android NDK" and guess it should work on Android.

Would that be possible on iPhone iOS or can it only be done in Objective-C?

In case of a GUI layer "on top" of the daemon - would it make sense to reuse the c socket util and the use Objective-C and Java for iOS and Android respectively - with some kind of communication between.

Finally, I prefer c++ - is that possible on iOS also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create UDP server using C++ to embed in cross platform iOS and Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215514/create-udp-server-using-c-to-embed-in-cross-platform-ios-and-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Android code is written in Java so you are just making your life hard by writing your daemon in C. If you look in [Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) you will see that it is straightforward to have a part of your application that runs as a service.

IOS is even more restrictive than Android because it does not support Java at all. However you might be able to do what you need [using XMLVM to compile Java for the iPhone](http://www.xmlvm.org/iphone/). If your server is not very complex it would probably be easier to just rewrite it in Objective C.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its c, c++ or java for me. Are you saying that it is not possible to code in c/c++ on IOS? Thanks for the links.

Comment: You can write C++ for IOS but it is not mainstream. If you can handle C, C++ and Java then it should not be hard to write your server code over again in Objective C.

Comment: Android has NDK and supports C/C++ sockets programming.

Comment: C++ is as native for Android as Java is.

Answer (score 1):

You can call C/C++ code directly from Objective-C code on iOS. It's even easier to integrate C/C++ code on iOS than on Android, where you need a very syntax specific JNI layer between Java and C++.

I would say that C/C++ is MORE native on iOS than on Android. C/C++ files can be added directly to the XCode project, and will be compiled with CLANG.

I am adding this as an answer because I believe the other answer to be mostly wrong, including the comments underneath it.