# Create UDP server using C++ to embed in cross platform iOS and Android app

Tags: android, c++, ios, c++11, cocos2d-x

I am developing a cross-platform mobile game (iOS and Android) using cocos2d-x.
Most of my code is written in C++, with OS specific code in Objective-C / Java / Swift using a bridge.

I was wondering if anyone has used any C++ library to host a UDP server within their app ?

EDIT: So far I have found many platform specific solutions (using Java for Android, and cocoaasync etc for iOS), but nothing specifically in C++ which has been used for a cross platform app.

Edit: I would prefer a solution without boost. Preferably something simple to include like adding a couple of files to a project.

Comment: I believe Boost (just google it, it is a cross platform C++ library) has versions of sockets both UDP and TCP.

Comment: libuv is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

h file:

```
#include "Queue.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#define MAXBUFFER_SIZE 1024

class UDPServer {
public:
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @port the port on which the UDP server is listening for packets.
     */
    explicit UDPServer(unsigned short port);

    /**
     * Destructor
     */
    ~UDPServer() = default;

    /**
     * Setup the server.
     */
    void setupServer();

    /**
     * Get a single message.
     * For demonstration purposes, our messages is expected to be a array of int
     */
    bool getMessage(std::array<int, 4>& message);

    bool getIPAddress(std::array<int, 4>& message);

    void setFoundIP();

    bool isReady();

    void nextPort();

    int getPort();

private:
    bool _isBoundToPort = false;
    /**
     * The server port.
     */
    unsigned short port_;
    bool isFoundIP = false;
    /**
     * The thread-safe message queue.
     */
    Queue queue_;
    Queue _ipAddresses;
    /**
     * The UDP server function.
     */
    int UDPServerFunc();
};
```

cpp file:

```
#include "UDPServer.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/**
 * This function parses an incoming message with the following format: 1;234;-89;-53;
 *
 * A valid message consists of 4 integer values separated by semicolons.
 */
inline std::array<int, 4> parseMessage(const std::string& input);
inline std::array<int,4> parseIp(const std::string& input);

UDPServer::UDPServer(unsigned short port)   {
    port_ = port;
}

bool UDPServer::getMessage(std::array<int, 4>& message) {
    return queue_.pop(message);
}

bool UDPServer::getIPAddress(std::array<int, 4>& message) {
    return _ipAddresses.pop(message);
}

void UDPServer::setFoundIP(){
    isFoundIP = true;
}

bool UDPServer::isReady(){
    return _isBoundToPort;
}

void UDPServer::nextPort(){
    port_++;
}

int UDPServer::getPort(){
    return port_;
}

void UDPServer::setupServer() {
    // Launch the server thread.
    std::thread t([this](){
        UDPServerFunc();
    });
    t.detach();
}

int UDPServer::UDPServerFunc() {

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    int sockfd;
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Filling server information
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv

    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port_);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if (::bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    _isBoundToPort = true;
    while (true)  {
        // Read the next message from the socket.
        char message[MAXBUFFER_SIZE];
        socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        ssize_t n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)&message, MAXBUFFER_SIZE, MSG_DONTWAIT,
                     (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, (socklen_t*)&len);
        if (n > 0) {
            message[n] = '\0';
            // Parse incoming data and push the result on the queue.
            // Parsed messages are represented as a std::array<int, 4>.

            if(!isFoundIP){
                _ipAddresses.push(parseIp(message));
            }else{
                queue_.push(parseMessage(message));
            }
        } else {
            // Wait a fraction of a millisecond for the next message.
            usleep(100);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I removed any unnecessary code from my answer, as the meat really is just the code above. If anyone needs the extraneous functions as well, I shared the code on [Github](https://github.com/totallyawesome/Embeddable-UDP-Server-For-Mobile-Applications/blob/master/UDPServer.cpp), and will add some examples later on too.

The above code is really simple and has a couple of parse functions for extracting an IP address, or a set of four numbers delimited by semicolons. The above code is simple enough to modify yourself for your own custom messages.

Queue.h is just a simple thread safe queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can most probably use Valve's GameNetworkingSockets, https://github.com/ValveSoftware/GameNetworkingSockets

They have very limited external dependencies, so you should be able to compile them for both iOS and Android

You can also take a look at this list: https://github.com/MFatihMAR/Awesome-Game-Networking, where there is a list of libraries that you can alternatively try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ASIO Standalone](https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone.html) library. It is the same library available as [boost/asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), but it doesn't require any other boost libraries. I have used [boost/asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) in exactly this type of project (Android/iOS) and it is by far the most superior solution.